# Reading List<Item> with Retrofit from XML API

Tags: java, android, xml, retrofit

I'm trying to use Retrofit with SimpleXmlConverter to read data from my API.

My class Comment looks like:

```
@Root
class Comment {
  @Element
  private String text;
}
```

I would like to read list of comments from XML:

```
<comments>
  <comment>
    <text>sample text</text>
  </comment>
  <comment>
    <text>sample text</text>
  </comment>
</comments>
```

In my interface there is a method:

```
@GET("/lastcomments")
ArrayList<Comment> lastComments();
```

but when I call  lastComments() Retrofit throws:

```
 Caused by: retrofit.RetrofitError: java.lang.ClassCastException: libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
        ...
 Caused by: retrofit.converter.ConversionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
        at com.mobprofs.retrofit.converters.SimpleXmlConverter.fromBody(SimpleXmlConverter.java:76)
        ...
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
        at com.mobprofs.retrofit.converters.SimpleXmlConverter.fromBody(SimpleXmlConverter.java:72)
```

Is there possible to read list directly from API or I have to create wrapper:

```
@Root(name="comments")
class CommentsList {
  @Element(name="comment", inline=true)
  List<Comment> comments;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Sorry I know this is probably too late but here is the answer:

You need to use an ElementList attribute:

```
@Root(name="comments")
class CommentsList {
    @ElementList(name="comment")
    List<Comment> comments;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use your CommentList class. The interface should be:

```
@GET("/lastcomments")
CommentList lastComments();
```

for synchronous calls or

```
@GET("/lastcomments")
void lastComments(Callback<CommentList> callback);
```

for asynchronous calls.